# jPanel visible on mouse location

Tags: java, applet, mouse, jpanel

I have an applet in which I desire to show a jPanel on mouseover. That part is covered.
What I really wish is that the jPanel appears on the current mouse location.

How can I achieve this?

I'm using NetBeans, if you think it's relevant. :)

Comment: *"show a jPanel on mouseover."*  What is in this panel?  What does it do? *"appears on the current mouse location"*  DYM top left corner, middle of the width x height?  As a bit of general advice, don't come here talking about what you really 'wish'/'want' that is irrelevant.  What is relevant is the feature you are trying to offer, which might be better achieved by an entirely different strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void yourMouseMoveMethod(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      yourJPanel.setLocation(evt.getX(),evt.getY());
}
```

if you don't want it to move everywhre with the cursor, you have to add some condition for it